# FPDF - PHP Library - Spaces not working on UNIX system?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using the FPDF library to build a PDF document based on some MySQL tables.  The script runs flawlessly on my windows box, but when I run it on my Ubuntu machine, all the spaces mysteriously disappear.  For example:

"The cat ran quickly"  becomes  "Thecatranquickly"

this happens if I use ANY of the FPDF functions to write to the document.  Including:

```
$pdf->Write
$pdf->Cell
$pdf->Text
```

Anyone have any idea why the "" (space) character is not being printed in my PDF doc!?

Comment: Totally off-topic, but try http://www.tcpdf.org/. From what I understand, FPDF is essentially terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bumped into the same problem. It seems to be a Google Chrome issue, take a look at the following thread:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=7169b114e8ea33c7&hl=en